# Как в PhpStorm убрать автоматическое удаление лишних пробелов?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

Как мне убрать автоматическое удаление пробелов в *phpstorm*. Видимо, при автоматическом сохранении, он еще автоматически форматирует файл от лишних пробелов, из-за чего файл изменяется и в *git* улетают ненужные изменения, выглядит некрасиво.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно от этого избавиться?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так эти пробелы не нужны :) Ничего страшного, что в Git попадают, видимо просто какой-то «гений» отключил эту настройку.

Comment: There MUST NOT be trailing whitespace at the end of lines. https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/

Comment: @RomanGrinyov, просто некрасиво выглядит в гитхабе. И, к примеру, когда я открываю готовый проект и захожу в какой-нибудь файл, phpstorm автоматически удаляет эти пробелы и они улетают в гит, создается ощущение, что я делал в нем какие-то изменения (в этом файле), но по факту - нет.

Comment: В PhpStorm можно отменить изменения (`Ctrl + Alt + Z`), а если лишние пробелы удалятся в файле, где были изменения кода, то это нормально (во-первых, по стандарту; во-вторых, это не доставит проблем кодревьюеру).

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего у вас включена опция **format on save**.

Зайдите в раздел настроек **Tools >> Actions on save** и отключите опцию **Reformat code**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На всякий случай [ссылка](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/reformat-and-rearrange-code.html) на документацию. Здесь описан ещё один способ отключения через фильтр по именам файлов.